# Creating database with only ldf file created 2 .ldf file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

When I run this query without specifying the ldf file it automatically creates the ldf file.

```
Declare @DBname nvarchar(50) = 'Test'
Declare @path nvarchar(50) = 'D:\DB'
Declare @query nvarchar(max) 

set @query = '

CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBname + '
ON
( NAME = ' +@DBname+',  
    FILENAME = '''+@path+'\'+@DBname+'.mdf'+''',
    SIZE = 1024,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 500 )  
'
exec (@query)
```

But when I run this query:

```
Declare @DBname nvarchar(50) = 'Test'
Declare @path nvarchar(50) = 'D:\DB'
Declare @query nvarchar(max) 

set @query = '

CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBname + '
ON 
( NAME = '+@DBname+'_log'+',  
    FILENAME = ''' +@path+'\'+@DBname+'_log.ldf'+''',
    SIZE = 100,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 100 );
'
exec (@query)
```

It creates 2 .ldf file without .mdf file. I don't understand why it creates 2 .ldf file and not mdf file automatically as it did in the above query:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As detailed in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) the correct way to specify that you are creating a log file is to use `CREATE DATABASE ... LOG ON (...)` - you are using `ON (...)`.

Your second bit of code simply specifies to create an MDF file (data file) using `.ldf` as the file extension. To create a log file you'd need to replace `ON` with `LOG ON` as below.

```
Declare @DBname nvarchar(50) = 'Test'
Declare @path nvarchar(50) = 'D:\DB'
Declare @query nvarchar(max) 

set @query = '

CREATE DATABASE ' + @DBname + '
--Create the data file using ON
ON 
( NAME = '+@DBname+',  
    FILENAME = ''' +@path+'\'+@DBname+'.mdf'+''',
    SIZE = 100,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 100 )
--Create the log file using LOG ON
LOG ON
( NAME = '+@DBname+'_log'+',  
    FILENAME = ''' +@path+'\'+@DBname+'_log.ldf'+''',
    SIZE = 100,
    MAXSIZE = unlimited,
    FILEGROWTH = 100 );
'
exec (@query)
```

In both cases your code creates a SQL data file, and the log file is automatically created using the settings in the `model` database. The only difference between the two is the name of the file - SQL Server will accept any file extension (or even complete lack of) as the name of the database files.